# These odd stains for appeared in the top room of my house. They weren’t here a couple of days ago. Could they be mold? Water stains?

Tags: water, mold, stain

[Blotchy stains on the ceiling. These go all around the room.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mmWO.jpg)

[[image: picture]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like water.  Check your roof.

On a bonus note, you at least know exactly where a ceiling joist is....

Answer (score 2):

Leaks like that are typically from a roof leak. If your shingles are older than 15 or 20 years old, it may be time for a new roof. There could be tabs missing on the roof from high wind, that would create a leak.

Other points to consider is ductwork and condensate lines. In summer, with high humidity, ductwork can sweat and drip water from a low spot in the ductwork if the pipe wrap insulation is absent or missing in a spot in the attic.

I have seen a PVC condensate line crack from freezing in the winter because a low spot was allowed or created in the drain line, and when froze it cracked. Summer happens, the condensate line does what it does, and the crack in it does what it does.